# How to prove that $\gcd(2n^3-14n+2,n+3) = \gcd(n+3,10)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

We have $\alpha=2n^3-14n+2$ and $\beta=n+3$,

How can we prove that the $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=\gcd(\beta,10)$,

and what are the possible values for this $\gcd$.

Comment: Actually, i was trying to write $\alpha=\beta*k+10$

Comment: A quick hint for the second half: if $k$ is a _greatest common divisor_ of $\beta$ and $10$, then it's certainly a _divisor_ of $10$.  What are those divisors?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ By [Euclid](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242), $\,\gcd(n\!-\!a,\,f(n)) = \gcd(n\!-\!a,\,f(n)\ {\rm mod}\ n\!-\!a) = \gcd(n\!-\!a,\color{#c00}{f(a)})\ $ for any polynomial $\,f(n)\,$ with integer coefficients, since  $\,{\rm mod} \ n\!-\!a\!:\ n\equiv a\,\Rightarrow\, f(n)\equiv \color{#c00}{f(a)}\ $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767543/242) (or by the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

Yours is special case $\ f(n) = 2n^3-14n+2,\,\ a=-3,\ $ so $\,\color{#c00}{f(a)} = f(-3) = \color{#c00}{-10}\ $ so the above yields that $\, \gcd(n\!+\!3,f(n)) = \gcd(n\!+\!3,-10) = \gcd(n\!+\!3,10).$

Answer (score 1):

$2n^3-14n+2 = 2n^2(n+3)-6n(n+3)+4(n+3)-10$ so it easily follows that $\gcd(\alpha, \beta) = \gcd(\beta, -10) = \gcd(\beta, 10)$.

The value of this gcd is $d$ such that $d|10$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$2n^3-14n+2=(n+3)(2n^2-6n+4)-10$$